# Lipschitz continuity on product space

Tags: analysis

Let $X,Y$ be real Hilbert spaces. Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ and let the operator $A^{\ast}$ denote the Hilbert-adjoint. Given the mapping $X\times Y\ni(x,y)\mapsto F(x,y)=\big(A^{\ast}(A(x))+A^{\ast}(y),\ A(x)\big)\in X\times Y$. How do I show that $F$ is locally Lipschitz?

Comment: Take a difference and use the fact that $A$ and its adjoint are bounded operators.

Comment: Well, I am having trouble to do this on $X\times Y$. I was thinking of proceeding component-wise, e.g. $\lVert A(x_1-x_2)\rVert\leq\lVert A\rVert_{\mathcal{L}(X,Y)}\lVert x_1-x_2\rVert$, but I don't know how to end up with s.th. like $\lVert (x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\rVert_{X\times Y}$ on the right side of the inequality...

Comment: I think $||(x_1, y_1)-(x_2, y_2)||_{X\times Y}:=||x_1-x_2||_X +||y_1-y_2||_Y$.